# Mac OSX: strange shaking (jitter) of screen

Tags: macos, screen

I noticed that sometimes a strange interference in rendering happened on my screen. I thought it was some minor issue with hardware. It happened 2 or 3 times a few months ago and I didn't think much of it.

Now it is happening much more frequently... Just for fun I tried to capture it with a screen recording... I thought I won't be able to do that anyway because it's in hardware.

But it turns out the interference / jitter does appear in the recording:

See here: the upper part jitters: http://youtu.be/6hA3ugF5sME

(better quality video: http://cl.ly/2i460o0X3e3O/download/jitter.mp4)

It's probably not Chrome rendering issue because the jitter is not just in one textbox as it maybe seems by non careful observation. Logo and "How to format" section are included. I also think that it didn't always happen while in Chrome, but I'm not that sure.

Very strange?

UPDATE: actually this could still be hardware issue, of course... for example problems with graphics card. It is just that it's not the hardware problem in some circuit on the screen at the end of pipeline... if it was, then I couldn't capture it in the recording...

Comment: PS: I'm now on Mavericks since one week ago. This happened on Mountain Lion too as I said, but now it's happening much more... but it seems to come in waves. I notice it a lot in an hour time frame for example then not at all for a day or more.

I also think it happens more when I played some (Flash) video in Chrome.

I tried to switch graphics card to "Discrete only" in gfxCardStatus and it was the same. I couldn't try with "Integrated only" because I have too many dependent apps open.

Comment: I have the exact same thing on my macbook pro (mid 2010). I also tried to change the chrome settings but it's still happening. I also noticed that it happens especially when there is a flash object in the page, but until now, it never happened under safari or firefox. Maybe something related with the flash plugin ?

Comment: Has it stopped causing problems for anyone else? I noticed that for about 2-3 months now I haven't seen this problem on my laptop..........

Comment: @user104793 I don't think StackExchange uses flash. The example posted is of the Ask Different Website. I say this because I uninstalled flash from my Mac recently and StackExchange sites work correctly in Safari, which unlike Chrome does not have native Flash support.

Answer (score 1):

That jitter is pure software. The CSS/javascript are not executing fast enough to prevent a redraw from being noticeable.

You could try reducing the load on the CPU by quitting other apps or just run some instruments on the pages where you see jitter and either block the js that is slow or decide to edit your text elsewhere and then copy/paste it to avoid seeing the constraints being redrawn.

The detailed video was awesome and allowed me to be certain what I was seeing was software.

Comment: Its weird because it is the top half of the browser window, and even though the element in the bottom half is part of the one that is affected in the lower top half, nothing happens to it.

Comment: @AMR I agree it's odd - until you get into the DOM and rendering engine, though - it might make perfect sense. Safari's inspector would be ideal to pick apart the elements that are wobbling.